# Custom back button view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to change the back button to a custom one.  If I create a UIBarButtonItem with just a custom title, that works fine.  However if I create one with a custom view, the button doesn't show, rather the default back button shows. Any ideas ?

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 51, 31);
[backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why that's not working. However I realized that I can just set this custom button as a leftBarButtonItem for my view

Comment: A little late, I know... but it's because you can't customize the back button.  It is what it is.  However, like you said, you can customize the `leftBarButtonItem`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setBackButtonBackgroundImage** ([Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:))

Usage:

```
let backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "img_name")!
backButton.setBackgroundImage(backImg, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

If you are using it in **all controllers**, use *appearance*:

```
let backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "img_name")!
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImg, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```